# Can a single iOS device be provisioned under two developer accounts

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I have two developer accounts with Apple.
A personal developer account and a corporate account via the company I work for.

I would like to be able to deploy apps that I write on my own using the personal account and deploy apps using the corporate account on to the **same iPad** - Can that be done?

Does provisioning tie the iOS device to a particular developer account?

Comment: HAve you tried doing it? I am sure if you will fail then there is no death penalty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does provisioning tie the iOS device to a particular developer
>   account?

No it doesn't.

From [Apple Documents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles.html):

> A development provisioning profile uniquely ties developers and
>   devices to a development team. A provisioning profile is valid for one
>   year. A device can be added to multiple provisioning profiles.

Comment: Thanks - Along the same lines If I use two macbooks to develop - one at home and other at work - do I have to add my provisioning again.
I guess I am confused as to - 
Is the provisioning for the developer account - the device or XCode?

Comment: You got a very good answer about that here => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861360/two-macs-one-iphone-developer-license-possible

Comment: There used to be a How To in the Provisioning Portal explaining how to export your credentials to develop on another machine. I can not find it now but basically you have to launch Keychain Assistant and export your Developer Certificate/Private Key, and install on the new machine.

Comment: Found it here:(Bottom of the page) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/10-Configuring_Development_and_Distribution_Assets/identities_and_devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW8