# private key missing in certificate downloaded from itunes

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am beginner of iPhone. I have no idea of upload app in itunes. I have make certificate and provisioning profile but when i downloaded certificate at that time no with private key.. so, give any suggestion which is apply in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things:

**1. Create a new certificate identity via the apple devloper portal** In this case you'll need to log into the apple developer portal and use the assistant, as part of this you will need to create and upload a CSR (Certificate Signing Request) which will also create the public and private keys on the machine. Apple sign the request and voila, a signed public/private certificate pair : [guide](https://appmakr.zendesk.com/entries/175966-how-to-create-and-upload-your-private-key-p12-into-your-appmakr-developer-account)

**2. Export the private key from the machine originally used to create the Certificate** This case is when your signing with an identity previously created, probably on an old machine or if (as in my case) your developing for a client that has their ID's already created. If you can't access the machine originally used to create the certificate identity you'll have to create a new identity as per the guide/assistant.

To do this, you will need to export your private key (a .p12 file), or public/private key pair via Keychain Access, and install the private key or key pair to the machine your developing on: [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861360/two-macs-one-iphone-developer-license-possible)