# In IOS How to create distribution certificate in client account

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I Would like to create IOS Distribution certificate for uploading app.i have client signing user name and password and i created distribution certificate after that i installed that certificate i have some warning message "Valid signing identity not found".Please any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons behind it. I was also stuck in this issue.

Just see my [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108503/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid-certifi/12294275#12294275).

A Beautiful [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688809/how-to-create-a-private-key-for-iphone-distribution-certificate) is Here.

If you need some Explanation on :

[How to create ios Certificates.](https://www.vbulletin.com/forum/content.php/506-Creating-your-iOS-Certificates)

Comment: Hi i dont know how to create private key and public key for client account

Comment: Thease are the steps i followed 1)open KeychainAccess->CertificateAssistant->Request a certificate from certificate authority and create new certificate and upload that certificate to client certificate tab and i download new certificate after installed that certificate i was creating distribution certificate

Comment: Ok.. I have added one Link to my answer. just Check it !